# Long lived AssemblyLoadContext

Tags: c#, .net-core

So this is what I'm trying to do. I would like to have a log lived AssemblyLoadContext instance in order to quickly execute loaded assemblies. 
When the assemblies updated event comes I would like to unload the context (I'm using .net core 3) and create a new context with versions of assemblies. When I try to do that however I get an error when unloading for the second time

[image: visual studio debugging error message]

so I'm guessing I'm doing something (very) wrong. I'm guessing the context doesn't get actually unloaded?

If the loaded assembly depends on some external dll I also get an error that that dll cannot be loaded, even though it is in the same folder. How can I prevent that?

Any advice would be very appreciated. This is my code

```
class Program
{
    private static AssembliesContext assembliesContext;

    const int iterations = 10;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            assembliesContext = new AssembliesContext();

            RunViaReflection();
            var wr = new WeakReference(assembliesContext);

            assembliesContext.Unload();
            assembliesContext = null;

            int retries = 0;
            while (wr.IsAlive && retries < 5)
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                retries++;
            }

        }

    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    static void RunViaReflection()
    {
        try
        {
            string dllPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..", "..", "..", "..", "Execution.Sample", "bin", "Debug", "netcoreapp2.2", "win10-x64", "publish", "Execution.Sample.dll");

            using (var fs = new FileStream(dllPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var assembly = assembliesContext.LoadFromStream(fs);

                var executableType = assembly.GetTypes()
                    .Where(x => typeof(IExecutableCode).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsInterface && !x.IsAbstract)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                IExecutableCode instance = (IExecutableCode)Activator.CreateInstance(executableType);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}

public class AssembliesContext : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    public AssembliesContext(): base(true)
    {

    }

    protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

---

I got rid of the error by casting the invoke result to Task (since it's an async method):

```
((Task)method.Invoke(instance, new object[] { })).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I also loaded the depending assemblies like this:

```
foreach (var ass in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
                    {
                        string path = Path.Combine(basePath, $"{ass.Name}.dll");
                        using (var dependantAssemblyStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            assembliesContext.LoadFromStream(dependantAssemblyStream);
                        }
                    }
```

I am still wondering how to manage a long lived AssemblyLoadContext since if I try to unload it as a class member it wil not unload, even if I set it to null and instantiate a new one.

Is a different approach warranted?

**Edit #2**

Right now I have a ConcurrentDictionary of WeakReference items which seems so work fairly ok, but every WeakReference in it loses it's target when the GC runs. Logical, but I still don't know how to make everything work.

If I do something like this

```
namespace AssemblyLoadTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AssemblyExecutor executor = new AssemblyExecutor();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..", "..", "..", "..", "Assembly", "Sinapro.IoT.Testing.DotNetRuleTestImplementation.dll");
            executor.Execute(assemblyPath);

            Console.WriteLine($"Iteration {i} completed");

            if (i > 0 && i % 10 == 0)
            {
                executor.Clear();
            }
        }

        executor.Clear();

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
}

public class AssemblyExecutor
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext> references = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext>();

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public void Clear()
    {
        var keys = references.Keys.ToList();
        foreach (var k in keys)
        {
            references.TryRemove(k, out CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext ctx);

            ctx.Unload();
        }
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Console.WriteLine("GC called");
    }

    public void Execute(string assemblyPath)
    {
        var wr = references.AddOrUpdate(
                    assemblyPath,
                    (k) =>
                    {
                        return CreateReference(assemblyPath);
                    },
                    (k, existingReference) =>
                    {
                        if (existingReference == null || !existingReference.Assemblies.Any())
                        {
                            return CreateReference(assemblyPath);
                        }

                        return existingReference;
                    }
                );



        ExecuteAssembly(wr);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private void ExecuteAssembly(CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext context)
    {
        //CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext context = wr.Target as CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext;
        if (context == null)
            return;

        var assembly = context.Assemblies.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ExportedTypes.Any(t => t.Name == "TestEntry"));

        var types = assembly.GetTypes().ToList();

        var type = assembly.GetType("Sinapro.IoT.Testing.DotNetRuleTestImplementation.TestEntry");

        var greetMethod = type.GetMethod("Execute");

        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var result = greetMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { null, null });
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext CreateReference(string assemblyPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Creating new context");
        var context = new CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext(assemblyPath);
        using (var fs = new FileStream(assemblyPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var assembly = context.LoadFromStream(fs);
        }

        return context;
    }
}

public class CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    private AssemblyDependencyResolver _resolver;

    public CollectibleAssemblyLoadContext(string path)
        : base(isCollectible: true)
    {
        _resolver = new AssemblyDependencyResolver(path);
    }

    protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        var deps = AssemblyLoadContext.Default;
        var res = deps.Assemblies.Where(d => d.FullName.Contains(assemblyName.Name)).ToList();
        if (res.Any())
        {
            return Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(res.First().FullName));
        }

        string assemblyPath = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName);
        if (assemblyPath == null)
            return null;

        return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
    }
}
```

}

everything runs fine, but the memory consumption keeps increasing. I find it curious though, since there shouldn't be any reference to the AssemblyLoadContext anymore so the GC should've cleared it?

Comment: Crashing the debugger is not so useful.  Such bugs always get a long time to get fixed, the pragmatic solution is to just not call Unload() when Debugger.IsAttached returns true.

Comment: See my edit of the question, I managed to fix the error. I'm still wondering if I can unload the context when it's referenced and long lived.

Comment: So, anyone more enlightened than me about this topic? :)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2317